# Show content of other cells that have same text before character "-"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets.

SHEETS 1 contains a column with some SKU'S with this structure:

```
GM1012-01

GM1012-04

GM1012-06

9431-01

9431-02

etc..
```

---

SHEETS 2 will contain these 2 columns

```
GM1012-01     |  GM1012-04,GM1012-06  

GM1012-04     |  GM1012-01,GM1012-06  

GM1012-06     |  GM1012-01,GM1012-04  

9431-01       |  9431-02

9431-02       |  9431-01
```

What I need to do is to starts from Sheet 2.
Search if in Sheet 1 are present sku with same code before "-" and then show all of them comma separated, excluding the one in the first column.

It's two hour I'm trying to do it :(
thanks

Comment: Could you please provide any output results?Also do you try VBA?

Comment: I don't know where to start, so I don't have any results :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correct this may help you:

```
        Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim Lrow1 As Long
        Dim Lrow2 As Long
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim str2 As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim j As Long
        Dim Counter As Long
        Dim TopNu As Long

            Lrow1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Lrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Sheet2.Range("B2" & ":B" & Lrow2).Clear

            For i = 2 To Lrow1
                str1 = Left(Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value, InStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value, "-") - 1)
                For j = 2 To Lrow2
                    str2 = Left(Sheet2.Cells(j, "A").Value, InStr(Sheet2.Cells(j, "A").Value, "-") - 1)
                    If (str1 = str2) And Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value <> Sheet2.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                        If Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value = "" Then
                            Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value
                        Else
                            Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value & "," & Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value
                        End If
                        If Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value <> "" Then
                            Counter = (Len(Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value) - Len(Replace(Sheet2.Cells(j, "B").Value, ",", ""))) / Len(",")
                            If Counter = 0 Then
                                Sheet2.Cells(j, "C").Value = 1
                            Else
                                Sheet2.Cells(j, "C").Value = Counter + 1
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
            Lrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To Lrow2
                If Sheet2.Cells(i, "C").Value <> "" Then
                    TopNu = Sheet2.Cells(i, "C").Value
                    Do Until TopNu = 0
                        If Sheet2.Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
                            Sheet2.Cells(i, "D").Value = TopNu
                        Else: Sheet2.Cells(i, "D").Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, "D").Value & "," & TopNu
                        End If
                        TopNu = TopNu - 1
                    Loop

                End If
            Next i
    End Sub
```

Results:
Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Make sure that:

- In Sheet1 you have SKUs in column A starting from A2.
- In Sheet2 you have SKUs in column A starting from A2.

For farther assistants see images.

Instructions:

- Open Excel and press First ALT and then F11.
- Insert and press Module.
- Delete everything from the module,copy paste the code and press F5.
- Visit excel and review the results.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not a developer or Excel guru, where should I put this code?

Comment: What if if I want to add a third column in sheet 2 where to show numbers like 3,2,1? It will count number of SKU in column 2. In your example you'll have 
2,1 for row 2,3,4 and 1 for row 5,6

Comment: Perfect.could you be more specific please?what numbers?Please provide more details.

Comment: It's a simple count of how many sku's are present in OUTPUT column. It's like a countdown.. hope is clear, sorry for my english

Comment: @Luca Frank Guarini hope work!Clear module, copy paste the new code and press F5!

Comment: Done. It simply added a new column with number of sku in column B.
I need something like col D https://snag.gy/Yl7Rud.jpg

Comment: Column C with the count is corrrect?

Comment: Please explain what are those number in Col D

Comment: I uploaded all real SKU and now I get this error when click on play https://snag.gy/g4eUhT.jpg

Col D shows comma separated numbers. First number is the count of SKU in col 2. Last number is 1(one). We need to display count number and all numbers to arrive to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182592/discussion-between-error-1004-and-luca-frank-guarini).